# Setting a CIDR Block When Creating a Subnet on Amazon Web Services

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-vpc

I'm currently going through the ["Getting Started"](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/gettingstarted/latest/wah-linux/getting-started-prereq.html) docs with AWS and I'm running into a problem while going through the very last subsection in the getting started doc.

**To add two private subnets to your VPC Step 6: In CIDR block, enter 10.0.2.0/24.**

I have tried my best to follow these steps exactly, but I get stuck here because when putting in this CIDR block I get an error message stating:

> 10.0.2.0/24 is not within the range of 172.31.0.0/16

What can I do to get around this? Is it possible the documentation is out of date or did I do something wrong in my previous steps? I have already double-checked that I followed everything as it says and still run into this error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's an issue with those docs.  I'd suggest ignoring the part that says "To test whether you have a default VPC" and go right to the part that says "To create a VPC", and create the specified VPC with the CIDR 10.0.1.0/24 (as instructed.)  Although you likely do have a default private VPC with CIDR 172.31.0.0/16, the subnets they give you later on won't work with that VPC.

Later, when you create your subnets, be sure to select the VPC that you created with 10.0.1.0/24 and not the default.

The problem with those docs is that they tell you you can skip creating your own VPC, but don't give you the right CIDRs to use with it.

Comment: Thank you for your response! I had a feeling I wasn't following the documentation wrong. It's worked out so far!